# Clearcase CCRC command 'checkin' failed: Unable to create pathname for file

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I have CM Server for ClearCase Remote Clients in windows 2003 server.
Installed package in server.

I'm getting below error in CCRC client:

> "CRVAP0087E CCRC command "checkin" failed: Unable to create pathname for 
>   file "C:\ccweb\v973012\v973012_Latest_FMC": Permission denied"

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to troubleshoot right issue is to go directly to the CCRC server, under the CCRC web (snapshot) view and type:

```
cd c:\ccweb\v973012
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

That way, you see with which group the user has created the CCRC view in the first place.
That group must be one of the groups associated with the Vob of the element being checked-in.

Check also [this technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21411191):

> During the installation of Rational ClearCase, you are asked for a temporary directory to use during the installation to unzip large artifacts.
>   This temporary directory is used to preserve user configuration settings during an update or uninstall process.
>   If you specify a directory that is mounted on a file system that is separate from the installation directory, the file permissions and owners are not preserved when the files are moved across the file systems.

Finally, check for any trigger set on the Vob: they can have an unwanted side-effect with that CCRC 'checkin' operation.

---

In the specific case of the [OP mth123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664441/mth123), he suggests:

> Go to the Windows Explorer and try these steps:
>
> - Go the the following directory: `C:\ccweb`
> - Rename the folder `v123412` to `V123412` (Only change the first letter and put "`V`" capitalized.)
> - Check if the problem is solved.

So depending on the actual tag of the view, this could be an issue about case-sensitive path.

Comment: can you pl give me some exact steps that can be resolve this issue ?

Comment: @mth123: the first step is to have access to the CCRC server, and go to the root directory of the web view (usually under `<clearcase_intallation>/var/ccweb`: for instance, `D:\Homeware\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\var\ccweb\aView`) and type `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`. You can then check any ACL issues based on the rights of the user's view.

Comment: i got a fix from IBM , pl use if any one have this issue.
-----
I would like to suggest you to go to the Windows Explorer and try these steps:
 - Go the the following directory: C:\ccweb
 - Rename the folder v123412 to V123412 -> Only change the first letter and put "V" capitalized.
 - Check if the problem is solved
_______

Comment: @mth123: interesting. What would be this fix?

Comment: go to the Windows Explorer and try these steps: - Go the the following directory: C:\ccweb - Rename the folder v123412 to V123412 -> Only change the first letter and put "V" capitalized. - Check if the problem is solved

Comment: @mth123: interesting, I have included your fix in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The latest patch caused this issue. While applying patch CC preserving some file inclusing ccweb folder. while restoring those folder during post install these directory might have changed with lowercase/upper case.  This is currently with IBM queue.

If you are going to upgrade CCRC please make a copy of ccweb directory with proper ACL or use ccopy.exe (clearcase utility)